# I try to add swiperjs into my angular 11 project but showing 'swiper' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I want to use [swiperjs][1] in my angular project. So read their documentation and did all steps they told me to do. but it shows an error saying **'swiper' is not a known element: 1. If 'swiper' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this**
here I did so far

1. npm i swiper,
2. import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular' to app.module;
3. add ./node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" to angular.json,

My HTML:

```
<swiper >
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
</swiper>
```

ts file:

```
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'gameClan';
  swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100,
  });
}
```

where did I make mistake? i uninstall and reinstall this package two times but the problem remains the same
[1]: https://swiperjs.com/angular

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after installing [ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) package, issue was resolved. Follow documentation steps.

i was using angular 11, "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^8.0.2" & "swiper": "^8.0.7",

Answer (score 0):

Import `SwiperModule` to the closest module to your component where you use it.

```
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added it to your imports array in AppModule.